# Interface with two different implementations

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have an interface `Person` and I have 2 classes `Female` and `Male` that implement the interface.

For the Female class, I have a method `getPregnancyMonth` that my Male class does not have. Adding that method to my interface `Person` becomes a problem as my `Male` class now needs to inherit that method from the interface; but the male would never be pregnant.

What would be a solution, do I need to `extend` Person instead of `implement`?

EDIT: Sorry if my question wasn't clear. In this case I have added both `get`/`set` methods from the `Male` and `Female` classes to the interface.

```
    static void Main(Form form) {
        Person person = Factory.createPerson(form.getGender());
        person.setName(form.getName());

        if ("F".equals(gender)) {
            person.setPregnancyMonth(form.getPregnancyMonth());
        }
    }
```

My question is, since my interface has `getPregnancyMonth`, my male has to add that method to the concrete class to implement the interface. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: please fix your question, this is not a factory pattern problem but a general question regarding inheritance and oo design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add `getPregnancyMonth` to `Person`. As you've discovered, that does not make much sense.

In object oriented programming, a base class/interface should (ideally) only contain the details that are common to each of its subclasses - since `getPregnancyMonth` is not common to both subclasses (it doesn't make any sense for a `Male`), it shouldn't be in the `Person` interface. Again I stress - this is talking about ideals.

As other answers have suggested, try to avoid the problem altogether, if you can. For example, you can use `instanceof` to detect whether a given `Person` is a `Male` or `Female`, and only call `getPregnancyMonth` if the `Person` is a `Female`.

**Edit**, in response to comment: the use of a factory method as described is largely pointless. If we ignore those people who don't wish to be labelled with a "normal" gender, you'll only ever create a `Male` or a `Female` object - you're much better just having `public static Female createFemale ( )` and `public static Male createMale ( )` methods in your `Factory`. This way, you'll avoid *all* this trouble you've been having. It'll also get rid of the string being used like a enum (i.e. "male", or "female" as an argument to `getPerson`), but that's a whole different matter...

If you still want to use a combined factory method, you can cast the result as a `Female`:

```
Female female = (Female) Factory.getPerson("female");
female.getPregnancyMonth ( );
```

Or, if you have a `Person` that may or may not be a `Female`, you can cast that too:

```
if (person instanceof Female)
{
    Female female = (Female) person;

    female.getPregnancyMonth( );
}
```

I can't say I'm overly fond of either of those approaches though - they have their place, but there's usually a better way.

Comment: but it will not let me compile, as when Person female = Factory.getPerson("female"), the method female.getPregnancyMonth() will not exist as Person does not have that method

Answer (score 5):

`getPregnancyMonth` Should not be in the interface of `Person`.

Personally...no pun intended...I think you should create `Person` as an abstract class as female and male will share a lot of the same attributes and functions.

Then you could create Female and Male interfaces that reflect unique functionality for each sex.

Comment: Or you can also keep Female and Male as Concrete Classes.

Answer (score 3):

There should be no need to move that method into the `Person` interface. The main trick is that when it comes time to execute the `getPregnancyMonth()` you must ensure you're dealing with a `Female` instance instead of just a `Person` instance.

For example, if you need to process a bunch of `Person` objects that do not require any particular treatment, a method can be created to do so easily:

```
public static void processPeople(List<Person> people) {
    for (Person p : people) {
        p.someMethod();
    }
}
```

However, when you must deal with the `getPregenancyMonth()` method, you must ensure that your method only accepts `Female` instances:

```
public static void checkBirthSchedule(Female girl) {
    girl.getPregnancyMonth();
    ...
}
```

In other words, as you are trying to get at, keep things as abstract as you can in higher up interfaces, but ensure you go to a more concrete type when needed. Using a technique like making a separate method with a more specific type of `Person` saves you at compile time from getting `ClassCastException`'s, which is very nice.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, `getPregnancyMonth` is not generic enough to be in a `Person` interface. It should probably be defined in the Female class only.

You may also define a second interface containing that `getPregnancyMonth`. Female will implement both.

Comment: +1 Put pregnancy related things on an interface focused on that behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Implement/Extend doesn't really matter here. You can either have isPregnant() always return false for Male, or you can just push the method directly into Female. Seeing as you think it is ridiculous that a Male would be pregnant, you would design your code such that it only calls isPregnant() on a Female, not just any person.

BTW By this I don't mean throw in an if(person instanceof Female), design your heiarchy as to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a broken object hierarchy, but taking it as stated, your interface needs two methods: isFemale() and getPregnancyMonth(). Then Male.getPregnancyMonth() throws an UnsupportedOperationException. A better approach would probably be to design your model so that a Male could never be put into a position where his pregnancy month would be asked.